# Does UIStackView have a delegate like a UITableView has?

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I am adding three buttons aligned horizontally in a `UIStackView`. The button is coming from a `Nib` file and I have an `@IBAction` in the owner of the nib.

My question is, I want to know the index of the button which was clicked. Does the `UIStackView` have a delegate  similar to `UITableView's` `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Currently I am doing an ugly way where I am setting a title to a button, and on button click, I get the button title and perform my action. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: :- UIStackView doesnot have a delegate. Why don't you add tags to the buttons.

Comment: Update your question with what you are currently doing and explain what your goal is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `StackView` doesn't have any delegate as you expected. Its better if you create your own delegate like below

```
protocol MyDelegate: class {
    func buttonSelectedAt(_ index: Int?)
}
```

On button click

```
delegate.buttonSelectedAt(sender.tag)
```

**Note:**  don't forget to give tags to your buttons so that you can identify each button separately.

Answer (score 1):

No, `UIStackView` does not have a delegate class. You may add actions programatically when you add the objects to the stack views.

Comment: I really wish Apple takes this into consideration and adds a delegate. The interfaces would be much cleaner. Thanks for your answer though